# How to add sml mode in emacs list-package?

Tags: emacs, sml

I want to use sml-mode for Emacs!
So I installed

1. emacs-24.2-bin-i386
   everything is ok, i can see emacs and can run it)
2. smlnj.msi
   when I try `(run-->sml & type:1+1; => val it=2:int)` it's ok too

If I run emacs <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> list-packages I can see the package.
But there is no sml-mode!

How can i add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume `list-packages` says that sml-mode is "available"?  That means that it is available for installation, but not yet installed.  Move point to the sml-mode line, hit <kbd>RET</kbd>, and then click the "Install" button in the window that appears.  After that, `list-packages` should say that it is "installed".

Alternatively, you can download the latest version from [the GNU ELPA archive web site](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/sml-mode.html) and install it with `M-x package-install-file`.

Comment: Could you check the value of `package-archives` (with `C-h v`) and check that it contains `http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/`?  sml-mode [should be in that archive](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/sml-mode.html)...

Comment: i did c-h v but i dont know what i have to do after!!!,and this elpa.gnu.org... link contains sml-mode,what i should do after download it!!  sorry i'm really beginner!

Comment: Once you have the file, you can install it with `M-x package-install-file`.